# Thymeleaf nested custom tag not executing standard dialect th: attributes

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm trying to write a custom tag with nested custom tags. Something like

```
<my:out th:if="true">
    <my:inside th:text="realtext">dummy</my:inside>
</my:out>
```

The `th:if` attribute on the `my:out` tag works fine while
the `th:text` attribute is ignored on the `my:inside` tag. Actually any `th` attribute is ignored in the inside tag.

I'm using a custom `AbstractElementModelProcessor` that iterates over the `IModel` elements.

My guess is that **the content of custom tags is not processed** when the standard dialect runs. How can I fix this?

**-- UPDATE --**

I made some experiments with a simple use case.

Given this HTML

```
<yada:test>
    <p th:if="true" th:text="ciao1">hello1</p>
    <yada:testInside th:if="true" th:text="Apples1">Inside1</yada:testInside>
</yada:test>
<yada:test>
    <p th:if="false">hello2</p>
    <yada:testInside th:if="false">Inside2</yada:testInside>
</yada:test>
```

and this processor implementation

```
public class TestTagProcessor extends AbstractElementModelProcessor {

    public TestTagProcessor(String dialectPrefix) {
        super(TemplateMode.HTML, dialectPrefix, "test", true, null, false, 12000); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void doProcess(ITemplateContext context, IModel model, IElementModelStructureHandler structureHandler) {
        System.out.println("---");
        for (int i = 0; i < model.size(); i++) {
            ITemplateEvent iTemplateEvent = model.get(i);
            if (iTemplateEvent instanceof IOpenElementTag) {
                final IOpenElementTag openTag = (IOpenElementTag) iTemplateEvent;
                System.out.println("openTag: " + openTag.getElementCompleteName());
            } else {
                System.out.println("node: " + iTemplateEvent.toString().trim());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get this output in the page

```
ciao1

Apples1
```

and this console output

```
---
openTag: yada:test
node: 
openTag: p
node: hello1
node: </p>
node: 
openTag: yada:testInside
node: Inside1
node: </yada:testInside>
node: 
node: </yada:test>
---
openTag: yada:test
node: 
openTag: p
node: hello2
node: </p>
node: 
openTag: yada:testInside
node: Inside2
node: </yada:testInside>
node: 
node: </yada:test>
```

so I deduce that the th: attributes are being processed, but on a "different level" than the custom tag.
In other words, `th:if` and `th:text` give the desired result, but the custom tag doesn't know about them.

I was expecting that `th:if="false"` would prevent the custom tag processor from seeing the node at all, but the console log shows that the node is processed as if `th:if` didn't exist. I tried with different PROCESSOR_PRECEDENCE values and nothing changes. Also the text content of the nodes is not changed by `th:text`.

Comment: What are the relative priorities of your custom dialect and the standard dialect? I would expect the custom dialect to be a higher priority (so that it is processed first) and that it would simply pass through the Thymeleaf attributes, such as `th:text="realtext"`, unchanged into its HTML output. Then, the standard dialect should be able to operate on the results (some standard HTML containing the unchanged `th:text` attribute).

Comment: I tried all possible priorities: lower, same and higher than the standard dialect. When priority is lower (executed before the standard) any th:if is ignored so no good. Also th:text would not be executed so I wouldn't be able to use the computed node text. When the priority is same or higher (executed concurrently or after the standard) th only works on the outer tag as stated.

Comment: I created a small dialect demo, similar to yours, but using `AbstractElementTagProcessor` instead of your model processor.  I tried using the `StandardDialect.PROCESSOR_PRECEDENCE` for my dialect - and I also tried with higher and lower precedence values. To my surprise, the results were the same as what you describe.

Comment: Test case added. It looks like the custom tag is being processed as if the th: attributes didn't exist, but they are not ignored.